# Group by 2 columns simultaneously while add some conditions to the groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I want to group my data by set and parts columns. If they have the same parts then group them all together. Please see the output column. I want to write a python script to generate exactly what the output column shows.

[image]

As you can see, set "6" has part "y" and set 7 also has part "y", so in this case, I want to output to be "y, u" because they share part "y".

I hope this makes sense!

Comment: unfortunately this grouping does not make sense to me :( maybe you can explain little more ..?

Comment: for example why first row `1,a` has this output `a,b,c,d,e,f,g`? It is not clear to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more like a network problem

```
import networkx as nx
G=nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'Set', 'Parts')
l=list(nx.connected_components(G))
c1=[[y  for y in x if y in df['Set'].tolist()  ]for x in l]
c2=[','.join(set([y  for y in x if y in df['Parts'].tolist()]))for x in l]
from collections import ChainMap

df.Set.map(dict(ChainMap(*map(dict.fromkeys, c1, c2))))
Out[167]: 
0     f,a,b,c,d,g,e
1     f,a,b,c,d,g,e
2     f,a,b,c,d,g,e
3     f,a,b,c,d,g,e
4     f,a,b,c,d,g,e
5     f,a,b,c,d,g,e
6     f,a,b,c,d,g,e
7     f,a,b,c,d,g,e
8     f,a,b,c,d,g,e
9     f,a,b,c,d,g,e
10                z
11              u,y
12              u,y
13              u,y
Name: Set, dtype: object
```

Comment: I was headed this route too.  However, I need to brush up on my 'ChainMap' collection methods. :)

Comment: Thanks!! This is why I love stackoverflow Python community!

You guys are super helpful. I have been stuck with this for days!!!

Comment: @Sotra yw:-) happy coding :-)

Answer (score 2):

One more solution using `networkx`'s minimum spanning trees and `BFS`

```
g = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='set', target='parts')

def parse(s):
    vals  = [item for sub in nx.algorithms.tree.minimum_spanning_edges(s, data=False) for item in sub]
    edges = set(filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, int), vals))
    vals  = sorted(set(filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, str), vals)))
    return({k: ','.join(vals) for k in edges})

m = map(parse, nx.connected_component_subgraphs(g))
df.set.map({k: v for x in m for k,v in x.items()})
```

Outputs

```
0     a,b,c,d,e,f,g
1     a,b,c,d,e,f,g
2     a,b,c,d,e,f,g
3     a,b,c,d,e,f,g
4     a,b,c,d,e,f,g
5     a,b,c,d,e,f,g
6     a,b,c,d,e,f,g
7     a,b,c,d,e,f,g
8     a,b,c,d,e,f,g
9     a,b,c,d,e,f,g
10                z
11              u,y
12              u,y
13              u,y
Name: set, dtype: object
```